# Input specific file prefix and type for algorithm using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm want to run the processing tool 'merge vector layers' (`native:mergevectorlayers`) using PyQGIS. The input layers are XLS files with the prefix "WeeklyContacts". A new XLS file is added to the directory each week and I want to run the algorithm every week to perform further spatial analyses.

I'd rather not have to manually select the files to being the script each week.

QGIS v 3.4

How do I input layers with the same prefix and file type rather than using code such as below?

```
params = {'LAYERS':['//gfwavsql/xxxx/WeeklyContacts-2018-10-12.xls','//gfwavsql/xxxx/WeeklyContacts-2018-10-16.xls','//gfwavsql/xxxx/WeeklyContacts-2018-10-23.xls','//gfwavsql/xxxx/WeeklyContacts-2018-10-30.xls','//gfwavsql/xxxx/WeeklyContacts-2018-11-06.xls'],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'memory:'}
processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", params)
```

[image]

Comment: Use `glob` module `glob.glob('WeeklyContacts*.xls')`

Comment: @FranRaga so something like...`params = {'LAYERS':[glob.glob('WeeklyContacts*.xls'),'//gfwavsql/xxxx/'],'CRS':None,....` Sorry I don't know how to combine that line of code. There is no reference to glob in QGIS 3.4 cookbook

Comment: `glob` is a python module, it has nothing to do with QGIS. This line return a list for example `glob.glob(r'D:\test\WeeklyContacts*.xls')` and you only need pass this list in LAYERS input. If you want add more path in this list, make list.append(...)

Comment: @FranRaga I'm sorry, would you be able to provide a complete answer with all lines of code? Again, I don't know if I need to use import os, glob at the start etc etc...

Comment: As @FranRaga mentioned, you could use it like: `params = {'LAYERS':glob.glob(r'D:\test\WeeklyContacts*.xls'),'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'memory:'}`. You may need to include `import glob` beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need this:

```
# import glob library
import glob 

# Create a list, glob return a list with file paths
layers = glob.glob('D:\test\WeeklyContacts*.xls')

# Put glob list result in 'LAYERS' processing input
params = {'LAYERS': layers ,'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'memory:'}
result = processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", params)

# If you want add result to canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result['OUTPUT'])
```